# Can I change /proc/pid/exe to reflect a different binary?

Tags: c, linux, filesystems

Im looking to change my processes /proc/pid/exe to reflect a different binary, or even no binary at all.

I've been looking into prctl, but I couldn't make much sense of the man page on it, heres the code I've tried

This code errors and shows "prctl: invalid argument", I searched through GitHub to find examples of this being used, and it's been used in the exact same way.

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

int fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
if(fd < 0)
{
    perror("open");
    return -1;
}

int ret = prctl(PR_SET_MM, PR_SET_MM_EXE_FILE, fd, 0, 0);
if(ret < 0)
    perror("prctl");

close(fd);
return 0;
}
```

Im open to any and all recommendations how or what I should try doing.

Preferably something that uses as few perms as possible

Messed around with it a little more on a different device and got the error message "prctl: device or resource busy", sadly this is leaving me with even more questions than answers

Comment: I believe the system call to do what you want is `exec()`.

Comment: I don't understand PR_SET_MM_EXE_FILE either, but note where the [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/prctl.2.html) says you need to "unmap all existing executable memory areas".  (Presumably including the one including the code where you do this.  Which sounds a lot like pulling the rug out from under yourself.)

Comment: @SteveSummit Probably should have clarified my intentions, Me and a buddy of mine were wondering how close you could get a process to resemble another while still functioning as itself. We've gotten nearly everything but `/proc/<pid>/exe`. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I wondered if it might have been something like that.  Needless to say, there's a reason this is hard!  (And, I would have thought, impossible.  But for that reason I wouldn't have thought PR_SET_MM_EXE_FILE would exist, yet there it is.)

Comment: @SteveSummit Did some more looking around and theres a mention on Twitter of using dlopen to 'open an object that unmaps the original executable mappings then call prctl PR_SET_MM_EXE_FILE'. This is getting a little out of my comfort zone, maybe you could shed some light on this idea.